# How can I check if a string is the name of a sub class of a specific class?

Tags: php

I want to check that string passed to a function would result in instance of certain class or subclass of it. The following example does the trick but I'm looking for a solution that does not require you to instantiate `$className` - as I actually do not really need it.

```
public function register($className, $baseAttributes) {
    $instance = new $className;
    if (!($instance instanceof AbstractFoo)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException();   
    }
    ...
}
```

I have another method that factors instances of `$className` but I want to fail as early as possible if wrong class has been supplied to the method during configuration. *For example something like*:

```
public function register($className, $baseAttributes) {
    if (!($className classof AbstractFoo)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException();   
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: [ReflectionClass](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php)

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to check if it implements a certain interface, as opposed to 'is or extends a certain class'?

Comment: is $className a fully qualified name?

Answer (score 4):

Well, you need [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php), and two methods `getParentClass()` & `isAbstract()`.

Here's a working example of what you need.

```
public function register($className, $baseAttributes) {

     $classReflection = new ReflectionClass($className);
     $parentClassName = $classReflection->getParentClass()->getName();
     if($parentClassName=="AbstractFoo"){
          throw new InvalidArgumentException();   
     }

     $parentReflection = new ReflectionClass($parentClassName);

     $isAbstract= $parentReflection->isAbstract(); // return true of false
     if (!($isAbstract)) {
          throw new InvalidArgumentException();   
     }
     //....
}
```

Other Solution using `isSubclassOf()` method of `ReflectionClass`

```
 public function register($className, $baseAttributes) {
     $classReflection = new ReflectionClass($className);
     if($classReflection->isSubclassOf("AbstractFoo")){
          throw new InvalidArgumentException();   
     }
     //....
}
```

Comment: @PaulCrovella, I have added as per your suggestions

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($className == 'AbstractFoo' || is_subclass_of($className, 'AbstractFoo')) …
```

See http://php.net/is_subclass_of.

If `AbstractFoo` is indeed `abstract` you can in fact skip the first equality check, since it will never be true.

Comment: The issue is that `is_subclass_of` requires instance as first parameter, not a string.

Comment: Sorry, I read the first example and the description, there is in fact additional example at the bottom that shows it could accept a string. Upvoted :)

Comment: It also says *"__A class name__ or an object instance."*

Comment: You are right - if you know what you are looking for. The argument is called `$object`, the description says `Checks if the given object has the class class_name as one of its parents or implements it.` Let's not get too into technicalities - the mistake was mine :)

Comment: True, the phrasing is not ideal… still, it's all in there. :o)